# How to store the values of ASPxTextBoxes inside DevExpress GridView DataItemTemplate during paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a gridview which I had attached there are columns which allow user to input data into textbox.

when user input/enter data in any of the textbox and then if he change the page index and then when he come back to old page, the data inputed in the textbox has been lost.

so is there any way so that I can maintain the value/data inputed in the textbox eventhogh user can visit the different page by changing page index of the grid view?

```
<dx:ASPxGridView EnablePagingGestures="True" SettingsPager-PageSize="5" ID="grdSelectedItem" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanged="grdSelectedItem_PageIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="ProductID">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Title" Caption="Product Tittle" Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CountItem" Caption="Count Items" Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False" Width="75px">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox  runat="server" ID="txtCountItem" Text='<%# Eval("CountItem") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because paging (also with sorting and grouping) updates `ASPxGridView` data with a callback sent to server, and all editors inside `DataItemTemplate` lose their value afterwards due to ASP.NET page life cycle. Hence, you need another way to store the textbox value inside item template, such like a hidden field or `Session` state variable by handling `Init` handler of corresponding control (also using `CustomUnboundColumnData` handler if the column with `DataItemTemplate` is an unbound column).

If you want to use hidden field (I think this is the easiest way), put a hidden field like this:

```html
<dx:ASPxHiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="hf"></dx:ASPxHiddenField>
```

Then, update the markup & code behind so that textbox inside `DataItemTemplate` has event handlers in both server and client-side by handling `Init` and `ValueChanged` (or `TextChanged`) events, which stores textbox value and set its value after callback:

**Markup**

```html
<script>
function grdSelectedItem_Init(s, e) {
    if (hf.Contains(s.cpHFKey))
        s.SetValue(hf.Get(s.cpHFKey));
}

function grdSelectedItem_ValueChanged(s, e) {
    hf.Set(s.cpHFKey, s.GetValue());
}
</script>

<!-- other stuff -->

<dx:ASPxGridView EnablePagingGestures="True" SettingsPager-PageSize="5" ID="grdSelectedItem" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanged="grdSelectedItem_PageIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="ProductID">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Title" Caption="Product Tittle" Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CountItem" Caption="Count Items" Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False" Width="75px">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtCountItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CountItem") %>' OnInit="txtCountItem_Init">
                    <ClientSideEvents Init="grdSelectedItem_Init" ValueChanged="grdSelectedItem_ValueChanged" />
                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>                
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void txtCountItem_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ASPxTextBox textBox = sender as ASPxTextBox;
    GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer container = textBox.NamingContainer as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer;

    textBox.JSProperties["cpHFKey"] = String.Format("{0}_txtCountItem_{1}", container.Grid.ClientID, container.KeyValue);

    textBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

    // other stuff
}
```

Related topics:

- [Values of ASPxTextBox placed in the DataItemTemplate are lost after grouping](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q426241/aspxgridview-values-of-aspxtextbox-placed-in-the-dataitemtemplate-are-lost-after-grouping)
- [How to store the values of ASPxTextBoxes inside DataItemTemplate during paging](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q293127/aspxgridview-how-to-store-the-values-of-aspxtextboxes-inside-dataitemtemplate-during)
- [How to bind ASPxGridView based on other grid's Selection and its UnboundColumn data](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2364/how-to-bind-aspxgridview-based-on-other-grid-s-selection-and-its-unboundcolumn-data)
- [The general technique of using the Init/Load event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18282/the-general-technique-of-using-the-init-load-event-handler)